# Is jquery.ui.js using blockUI feature?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-blockui

I am recently using jquery.blockUI.js library to block the page.

But I find conflicts in my page while importing both jquery.blockUI.js and jquery.ui.js libraries.

Also I did search in jquery.ui library and found following code snippet in it:

```
this._showDatepicker(this._dialogInput[0]);d.blockUI&&d.blockUI(this.dpDiv);d.data(this._dialogInput[0],"datepicker",a);return
```

I am confused whether jquery.ui is included with features similar to blockUI.

Can anyone help me which one to use (jquery.ui or jquery.blockUI) to block the page or part of the page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked through jquery datepicker and it is using blockUI if it is defined.

Answer (score 0):

No, jQuery UI does not use the jquery.blockUI library.

The feature of blockUI is probably what that code reference is about - but that library is not included with, nor referenced by jQuery UI.

I don't see an immediate reason on why you could not use both of these on the same page. Probably you have an issue with loading order or something of this nature.

I personally have it in production with both right now and have not had any issues along the lines of what you are talking about.